# Is there a simpler way to create a positive rectangle from two points?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, coordinates, rectangles

I have two sets of points, I want to create a rectangle from these two points that is always positive i.e. the lowest co-ordinate pair is the start point and the highest co-ordinate pair is the end point.

I have created a function that does this but it doesn't seem very elegant - is the a better way/built in functionality to do this?

```
Private Function CalculateDraggedRectangle(ByVal startX As Integer, ByVal startY As Integer, ByVal currentX As Integer, ByVal currentY As Integer) As Rectangle
    Dim rX, rY, rWidth, rHeight As Integer
    If currentX < startX Then
        If currentY < startY Then
            rX = currentX
            rY = currentY
            rWidth = startX - currentX
            rHeight = startY - currentY
        Else
            rX = currentX
            rY = startY
            rWidth = startX - currentX
            rHeight = currentY - startY
        End If
    Else
        If currentY < startY Then
            rX = startX
            rY = currentY
            rWidth = currentX - startX
            rHeight = startY - currentY
        Else
            rX = startX
            rY = startY
            rWidth = currentX - startX
            rHeight = currentY - startY
        End If
    End If

    Return New Rectangle(rX, rY, rWidth, rHeight)
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
Dim rX = Math.Min(startX, currentX)
Dim rY = Math.Min(startY, currentY)
Dim rWidth = Math.Abs(startX - currentX)
Dim rHeight = Math.Abs(startY - currentY)
Return New Rectangle(rX, rY, rWidth, rHeight)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Math.Min` and `Math.Abs` functions

```
rX = Math.Min(startX, currentX)
rY = Math.Min(startY, currentY)
rWidth = Math.Abs(startX - currentX)
rHeight = Math.Abs(startY - currentY)
```

---

Your approach can be simplified by treating the horizontal and vertical parts separately:

```
Private Function CalculateDraggedRectangle(ByVal startX As Integer, ByVal startY As Integer, ByVal currentX As Integer, ByVal currentY As Integer) As Rectangle
    Dim rX, rY, rWidth, rHeight As Integer

    If currentX < startX Then
        rX = currentX
        rWidth = startX - currentX
    Else
        rX = startX
        rWidth = currentX - startX
    End If
    If currentY < startY Then
        rY = currentY
        rHeight = startY - currentY
    Else
        rY = startY
        rHeight = currentY - startY
    End If

    Return New Rectangle(rX, rY, rWidth, rHeight)
End Function
```